# How can I process multiple push notifications in Android, before doing action

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In my chat app I send push notifications for new messages. Normally when app receives push it will send request to server to fetch info for new messages. My problem rise when user is offline for long time, and lot of pushes accumulated for that user. Then when he comes back online he receives all pushes at once. 
 So when many pushes come my app starts to make request for each push.
How can I process all pushes first and then make single request to server.

**Edit 1**

To fetch new messages from server I build request where I put last message id I have locally. Then server will return me all new messages after that message id.
This is my retrofit code.

```
public interface GroupChatFromDateInterface {
        @GET("/groups/{groupId}/show_messages.json")
        List<Message> groupMessages(@Path("groupId") int groupId,
                                    @Query("auth_token") String token,
                                    @Query("after_message_id") int messageId);
    }
```

Comment: post some code where you are making server request on getting the push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this issue is to use a `collapse_key` in the GCM message you send.

If all your GCM messages have the same `collapse_key`, when a device is offline the GCM server would store only one message for that collapse_key.

When the device is back online, it will receive just one GCM message, and your app will make a single request to your server.